# newrelic yml file contains uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I am integrating newrelic in my application. I wanted to have custom app name in newrelic.yml file. Code looks like

newrelic.yml

```
app_name: App <%= Rails.my_app_name %>
//some_more config
```

But when starting rails server, I see that log/newrelic.log file contains error.

Error is:

```
ERROR : Failed ERB processing configuration file. This is typically caused by a Ruby error in <% %> templating blocks in your newrelic.yml file.

ERROR : NameError: uninitialized constant NewRelic::Agent::Configuration::YamlSource::Rails
```

I get from the error that newrelic does not have any context of rails or its varibales. So the question is how can I access rails varibale inside newrelic.yml file?

Comment: What is ```my_app_name```? Can't find it in Rails API. If you want to take the name of the app I suggest ```Rails.application.class.parent_name```

Comment: @radubogdan Its a constant that is created in my config/initializers/create_name.rb script. I want to use to it in newrelics.yml file